# Aerospike : Does Java Client support mulitple filters on secondary indexes?

Tags: java, aerospike

Suppose I have created secondary indexes on **bin1** and **bin2**.
And I query using **Java** client as :

```
Statement stmt = new Statement();
stmt.setNamespace("test");
stmt.setSetName("myDemoSet");
stmt.setBinNames("bin1", "bin2", "bin3", "bin4", "bin5");
stmt.setFilters(Filter.equal("bin1", Value.get("sherlock")));
RecordSet rs = null;
try {
    rs = client.query(null, stmt);
} catch (AerospikeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This **works**. But if I add another filter :

```
stmt.setFilters(Filter.equal("bin1", Value.get("sherlock")), Filter.equal("bin2", Value.get("stackoverflow")));
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect on the output.
So is multiple filters supported currently by Aerospike Java Client?
If so, how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Old Answer:** *Currently you can only do a single predicate on a secondary index, either equals or between.*

**Update:** [Predicate filtering](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) was added in [release 3.12](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-aerospike-3-12/). You can use the  [PredExp](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) class of the Java client (see [examples](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/QueryPredExp.java)).

Comment: Thanks, any plan to support mutilple filters in near future ?